# How can I link libc.a into a shared library in arm-linux use arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: linux, linker, arm, shared-libraries, libc

In a project, my colleague create a static library, e.g liba.a, which linked with app.

In liba.a he overwrites the libc malloc() to his owner version.

I create a shared library libs.so which also linked with app.

The problem is when my libs.so linked with app, the malloc() used in my libs.so will be the one in liba.a, 
not the one in standard libc.so, this causes problems.

Then, I want static link the libc.a to my libs.so, I used -static -shared -fPIC flags for gcc.

But I always get arm-2012.03/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: arm-2012.03/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/libc.a(dl-tsd.o)(.text+0x14): R_ARM_TLS_LE32 relocation not permitted in shared object.

Does anyone have idea about it?

Thanks forward.

Comment: I think -static -share should not be mixed....

Comment: The following text is copyed from ld.pdf from codesurgery: "-static Do not link against shared libraries. This is only meaningful on platforms
for which shared libraries are supported. **This
option can be used with ‘-shared’**. Doing so means that a shared library is
being created but that all of the library’s external references must be resolved
by pulling in entries from static libraries."

Comment: @DavidChyi: That only says -static and -shared can be mixed, but not that it's a good idea. Compilers in general have many options that are not a good idea to use for normal applications. They are important for special cases like compiling kernel, bootloader, microcontroller code and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because code that goes in shared library must be compiled with `-fPIC` and code in static libraries isn't. If you managed to do it, the resulting executable would end up linked with libc multiple times, which would be really fragile anyway and probably crash sooner or later, so you shouldn't do it anyway. Therefore:

**Don't**. Dynamic libraries have to link against system libraries dynamically and any executable that links against any dynamic libraries also has to link system libraries dynamically.

I would also like to remind you, that linking GNU libc against non-GPL application statically is illegal, since LGPL only excepts dynamically linked code. This is on purpose to allow bugfixing the library without recompiling the executable for which source may not be available. It's rather common in Linux to upgrade shared libraries with bugfixed version without recompiling dependent executables; libc developers know how to do that.

Comment: @Hudec: Thanks for your kindly remind. My colleague has already changed his library to use standard malloc() in libc.so. But just for curious, Why the following example worked in PC gcc, but failed in ARM gcc:  $ cat libtest.c  
`#include <stdio.h>
void foo() { printf("%d\n", 42); }`

$ cat main.c

`#include <stdio.h>
extern void foo();
int main() { puts("The answer is:"); foo(); }`

`gcc -shared -fPIC libtest.c -o libtest.so -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lc  && gcc -c main.c -o main.o && gcc main.o -o test ./libtest.so && LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so ./test`
          ====> 42, worked.

Comment: @Hudec: Where can I find this information? _Don't. Dynamic libraries have to link against system libraries dynamically and any executable that links against any dynamic libraries also has to link system libraries dynamically._ And what is libc.a used for?

Comment: @DavidChyi: It depends on what the libc.a on that particular system you are trying it on actually contains. It may work on one particular installation and not on another. Many installations don't even have static libc installed.

Comment: @DavidChyi: Also ELF, the binary format used on most Unices, goes a long way to support the one definition rule. If you link the same object statically via separate dynamic objects, it will use one of the copies in both. So it will usually work, provided the versions are compatible and position independent. But other systems like Windows will happily use the copy it contains in each of the objects and if you mix the calls, it will really go crazy.

Comment: @DavidChyi: I have learned a lot about how dynamic linking works over time, but I don't really remember any one comprehensive source of information. Usually the rule of thumb is to use the default (which on Linux always means dynamic linking) unless you have a really good reason to change it and understand the implications.